# Как воспользоваться CRM Битрикс24 на своем сайте

Tags: vue.js, битрикс, vue-cli, битрикс24

Если на vue js пишешь frontend для сайта, как подключить к нему CRM от битрикса, и нужно ли это делать frontend'еру?

Начинающий, не понимаю сам принцип. Если на сайте необходимо создание возможности записи к специалистам по определенным дням, необходим блог со статьями и тд.

Как я могу использовать Битрикс24 в этих целях?

Comment: Не понятно, как по мне, можете подробнее рассказать?

Answer (score 0):

Да, вы можете поручить это фронтэндеру.

Он может через REST API Битрикс24 (https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/rest_help/) создавать лиды в CRM.